# ActiveScaffold thread-safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety, activescaffold

Multiple sources claim ActiveScaffold isn't thread safe:

- [ActiveScaffold CanCan bridge documentation](https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/CanCan)
- [A Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/activescaffold/c_QZ77VCJyw)

From those I gather controller level configuration changes and authorization aren't thread-safe. Is it safe to consider an application thread-safe if it doesn't use those components of ActiveScaffold? Are there any other features in ActiveScaffold that aren't thread-safe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not much in the way of official documentation on this matter, however there are two useful quotes from developers which may help you here. First, [in 2010, here on this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/activescaffold@googlegroups.com/msg04915.html) a developer stated:

> In the controller, using marked_records. Marked records are stored in session, 
>   so they only can be accessed from the controller. Model methods were a hack to 
>   get the model methods from current controller, but it was using class 
>   variables which is not thread safe.
>
> ActiveScaffold is not thread safe ATM, but I will fix current non thread safe 
>   code later and I don't want to add more non thread safe code. If model methods 
>   are needed I will add them using thread variables

This indicated the original intent was that there would not be thread-safety. However it was being developed.

After this point discussion on the matter seems to have become quiet and I cannot find any further official statements. However people commenting on resent versions have said that the only threading issue is that changes to active_scaffold_config must be placed inside some kind of lock in order to be safe and that the rest of the system should now be threadsafe.

Beware, I cannot find official docs to prove this, it is only based on the comments of users who have read over the code base so I would not guarantee this to always be the case, but given the comments of a dev saying no more non-threaded code would be added this is likely a safe bet.

Finally, note [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/activescaffold/issues/detail?id=732) it implies that the code-base is now nearly thread safe and threads can be used as long as you take a few precautions and use workarounds in a few places.

I am sorry I do not have a more authoritative answer here, the documentation on this is sparse and reading the code is difficult to be sure either way but this is the closest to sure I can get (it seems people have had success using it with threads in production at least).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and congratulations on receiving the bounty :)